# .htaccess blocking WP admin user's access to WP's admin features

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been looking for a way to hide the file extensions from URLs and I came across this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Go Daddy servers need the Options -MultiViews code below
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works beautifully until I found out that for some reason this was blocking WP admin features in my WP admin account, meaning I couldn't activate/deactivate plugins, add/edit/delete users and so on. So I was forced to remove the .htaccess file and now I have the .php extensions back in my URLs.

Is there a way of hiding the extensions from my URLs without losing my WP admin capabilities? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you want to hide the .php extension of admin urls in the first place? You can prettify the public-facing URLs in WP using [standard methods](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Comment: Hi Kevin. I appreciate your response. Well, I don't mind the .php extension neither in the admin URLs nor in the posts URLs. What I really mind is the .php extension in the page URLs of the website itself. Eg. I currently have http://www.adielrios.com/contato.php whereas I'd rather have http://www.adielrios.com/contato. The code I had does the job but at a high cost - blocking admin capabilities in the WP's admin panel (and I have no clue why that is), which is clearly not a desirable outcome. Is this feasible? =/ Thanks.